# Cannot change a property of WPF from a websocket event

Tags: c#, wpf, websocket

I am trying to change a property of WPF from a websocket event however I am encountering a problem where I get this exception: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6vj1.png

I googled the exception and it brought up this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=netcore-3.1

They said that I could use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to remove the exception (as seen in the screenshot). I did that on a render thread but I still get the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfGEH.png)

Secondly I tried to invoke the function the dispatch the thread onto the main thread which resulted into the error in the attempted solution. Strangely enough I had access to change the property according to the print debugging I did.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEDWd.png)

Comment: Can you try to move creating of bitmap inside the action as that one can also have a problem with access and if that does not help, share what PlayerImage is? Is that just Image control in your xaml file named PlayerImage?

Comment: Player image is a image uri  that should look like this : https://www.roblox.com/Thumbs/Avatar.ashx?x=420&y=420&userid=54904403

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I have run into this same issue in my searching and if this is more clearly answered others may find it helpful. That said what Andrej Dobes is correct this may just provide more clarity.

Based off of your response to the previous answer it looks as though you were still confused. The code would need to look similar to this on line 49 of your previous screenshot:

```
PlayerDataSocket.OnMessage += Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(PlayerDataSocket_OnMessage)
```

The `?` are added as not null checks and aren't necessary for your situation most likely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the dispatcher of the thread that created the object originally which I guess would be the UI thread since you're setting the image. When invoking dispatcher from static class directly you always get the one that is actually assigned to the actual thread, which means you would have to have the reference to a dispatcher of the thread that owns the object.

DispatcherPriority.Render does not say that you want to exeucute it on a render thread but it's setting the priority when it should be executed, you check more at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?view=netcore-3.1) about that.

To access the UI thread dispatcher you can use the code below, but then the UI thread actually needs to be the owner of the object you're setting

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

Comment: I still have the issue. Here is a screenshot of the error: https://i.imgur.com/6UGgsij.png